# (Android Media Player) Why can't use prepareAsync() instead of prepre() with AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am really a newbie in this (and also with the English ).
Lately , I spend reading (or at least try) about Android Media Player.

This time, I found this with Google: http://dev-space.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/StreamPlayer/src/com/pozheg/

I tried to play a mp3 file (http://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3) with the original source code and it worked great. But when I use prepareAsync() with my stream, the mMediaPlayer passes to release().

I'm trying to play an audio streaming using prepareAsync() instead of prepare() AsyncTask

**The question is:** why can not?

I know my question may be very stupid , but I want to learn with you .

**In this way:**

```
package com.myaudioservice.app;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;

/**
 * Service to serv MediaPlayer in background
 *
 * @author Eugeny Pozharsky
 */
public class PlayerService extends Service {
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private PlayerCallback callback;

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        PlayerService getService() {
            return PlayerService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    /**
     * Kill MediaPlayer to release resources
     */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Starts playing stream.
     * Note that we just start media player and do not obtain real URL of the stream.
     * So, URL that will be redirected by server will not work. To make such URLs works, adding
     * algorithm to obtain the real URL (f.e., create HttpConnection, connect to the server and
     * get real URL from connection).
     *
     * @param url String with URL of a server to connect
     */
    public void start(String url) {
        if (mediaPlayer == null) {
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        }
        if (isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
        }
        new Player().execute(url);
    }

    /**
     * Stops playing of the stream.
     */
    public void stop() {
        // stopping MediaPlayer in separate thread because it can take a time
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                    }
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    mediaPlayer = null;
                }
            }
        }).start();
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onStopped();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Is stream playing?
     *
     * @return true or false
     */
    public Boolean isPlaying() {
        return mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }

    public void setCallback(PlayerCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    /**
     * Background task to start MediaPlayer. It is used because starting playing of remote stream may
     * take long time and we must not block UI thread.
     * Also, this approach allows to cancel starting process (not implemented in current version)
     */
    private class Player extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        /**
         * This function called in UI thread and we callback to activity to update UI elements
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            if (callback != null) {
                callback.onPreStart();
            }
        }

        /**
         * This function called in UI thread and we callback to activity to update UI elements
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            if (mediaPlayer == null || !mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                // Start MediaPlayer fail.
                if (callback != null) {
                    callback.onStartFailed();
                }
            } else {
                if (callback != null) {
                    callback.onStarted();
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * This function called from separate thread and we do long-time operation in it
         *
         * @param strings params
         * @return null
         */
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                mediaPlayer.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                }
                mediaPlayer = null;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can someone help me? :(

Answer (score 1):

You must wait until stream is prepared before you call `start()`.
When you want to use `prepareAsync()` you should set `OnPrepareListener` to media player and call `start()` form it.

```
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you @KamilW I tried again using only `prepare()` and it worked, but I wonder if it is good practice for live stream :(. And another question I have looking at the code: Do I need to write twice `mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();` in `Start(String url)` and `doInBackground(String ... strings)`? Is not that redundant ?

Comment: You not supposed to use `preapare()` on the GUI thread because it may froze you app, but here you doing this in separate thread so its fine. One of this initialization looks redundant.

Comment: Thanks for answering @KamilW. I understand , I'll leave that. I have opened a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32450826/5195185) because I 'm obsessed with creating a 'fantastic application' (without errors)