# Making a smart Android Media Player app using Service, AsyncTask and Thread

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

**First of all:**
Sorry if I had misspellings. I'm from Paraguay and I am using Google Translate.

This may seem a little silly, and I'm a perfectionist and like any good developer and designer, do not want bugs in my projects. I am in the process of learning and hope to learn much with you

I have seen media player applications that allow the user to quickly and repeatedly press the play/stop button without killing the application, and that this is still functioning properly, so I read about `Services`, `AsyncTask` and `Thread`. Not only to play the sound in the background but also to not kill my application with UI errors. I have many questions yet.

I wonder if I'm on a good path using the following resource ([found online](http://dev-space.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/StreamPlayer/src/com/pozheg/)), but I have tried and the application dies when I press for several times the play/stop buttom or sometimes simply not play the song.

```
package com.myaudioservice.app;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;

/**
 * Service to serv MediaPlayer in background
 *
 * @author Eugeny Pozharsky
 */
public class PlayerService extends Service {
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private PlayerCallback callback;

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        PlayerService getService() {
            return PlayerService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    /**
     * Kill MediaPlayer to release resources
     */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Starts playing stream.
     * Note that we just start media player and do not obtain real URL of the stream.
     * So, URL that will be redirected by server will not work. To make such URLs works, adding
     * algorithm to obtain the real URL (f.e., create HttpConnection, connect to the server and
     * get real URL from connection).
     *
     * @param url String with URL of a server to connect
     */
    public void start(String url) {
        if (mediaPlayer == null) {
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        }
        if (isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
        }
        new Player().execute(url);
        Log.e("PlayerService", "start()");
    }

    /**
     * Stops playing of the stream.
     */
    public void stop() {
        // stopping MediaPlayer in separate thread because it can take a time
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                    }
                    //mediaPlayer.release();
                    //mediaPlayer = null;
                }
            }
        }).start();
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onStopped();
        }
        Log.e("PlayerService", "stop()");
    }

    /**
     * Is stream playing?
     *
     * @return true or false
     */
    public Boolean isPlaying() {
        return mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }

    public void setCallback(PlayerCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    /**
     * Background task to start MediaPlayer. It is used because starting playing of remote stream may
     * take long time and we must not block UI thread.
     * Also, this approach allows to cancel starting process (not implemented in current version)
     */
    private class Player extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        /**
         * This function called in UI thread and we callback to activity to update UI elements
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            if (callback != null) {
                callback.onPreStart();
            }
        }

        /**
         * This function called in UI thread and we callback to activity to update UI elements
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            if (mediaPlayer == null || !mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                // Start MediaPlayer fail.
                if (callback != null) {
                    callback.onStartFailed();
                }
            } else {
                if (callback != null) {
                    callback.onStarted();
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * This function called from separate thread and we do long-time operation in it
         *
         * @param strings params
         * @return null
         */
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            //mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                }
                mediaPlayer = null;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder if I should cancel my `AsyncTask` process at any time or if I should add/modify something that my application will not die. How should I do?
Someone can guide me?

I usually get the error (if it appears) in my logcast it is as follows:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)
```

For the Play/Stop button:

```
btn_control.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                control((!ON_PLAY) ? 1 : 0);
            }
        });

private void control(int est) {

        if(est==1){
            if (!hayConexion()) {
                Toast.makeText(Principal.this, getString(R.string.error_conexion_txt), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                if (mBound) {
                    mService.start();
                    ON_PLAY = true;
                }
            }
        }else if(est==0) {

            if (mBound) {
                mService.stop();
                ON_PLAY = false;
            }
        }

    }
```

**EDIT:**

Logcat:

```
09-08 03:13:08.333  32438-32474/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ native_setup
09-08 03:13:08.333  32438-32474/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ constructor
09-08 03:13:08.343  32438-32474/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ setListener
09-08 03:13:08.343  32438-32474/com.myaudioservice.app I/MediaPlayer﹕ path is null
09-08 03:13:08.343  32438-32474/com.myaudioservice.app D/MediaPlayer﹕ setDataSource IOException happend :
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: rtsp://ip/folder/file.stream
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1053)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:907)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:834)
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:988)
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:942)
            at com.myaudioservice.app.PlayerService$Player.doInBackground(PlayerService.java:156)
            at com.myaudioservice.app.PlayerService$Player.doInBackground(PlayerService.java:130)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-08 03:13:08.343  32438-32474/com.myaudioservice.app D/MediaPlayer﹕ Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
09-08 03:13:08.353  32438-32474/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ setAudioStreamType: 3
09-08 03:13:08.353  32438-32474/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
09-08 03:13:08.353  32438-32474/com.myaudioservice.app D/com.myaudioservice.app.PlayerService﹕ Preparing: rtsp://ip/folder/file.stream
09-08 03:13:08.353  32438-32474/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ setVideoSurfaceTexture
09-08 03:13:08.353  32438-32474/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ prepare
09-08 03:13:09.384  32438-32438/com.myaudioservice.app E/PlayerService﹕ stop()
09-08 03:13:09.394  32438-32495/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ isPlaying: 0
09-08 03:13:09.394  32438-32495/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ release
09-08 03:13:09.394  32438-32495/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ setListener
09-08 03:13:09.394  32438-32495/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ disconnect
09-08 03:13:09.544  32438-32438/com.myaudioservice.app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-08 03:13:09.544  32438-32438/com.myaudioservice.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4193eda0)
09-08 03:13:09.544  32438-32438/com.myaudioservice.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myaudioservice.app, PID: 32438
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
            at com.myaudioservice.app.PlayerService.reproduciendo(PlayerService.java:118)
            at com.myaudioservice.app.PlayerService.start(PlayerService.java:84)
            at com.myaudioservice.app.MainActivity.control(MainActivity.java:298)
            at com.myaudioservice.app.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:38)
            at com.myaudioservice.app.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:173)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4640)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19425)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**NEW LOGCAT:**

```
 09-08 14:49:24.360    9651-9651/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ isPlaying: no active player
    09-08 14:49:24.360    9651-9651/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ isPlaying: 0
    09-08 14:49:24.390    9651-9651/com.myaudioservice.app E/PlayerService﹕ start()
    09-08 14:49:24.480   9651-10534/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ isPlaying: no active player
    09-08 14:49:24.480   9651-10534/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ isPlaying: 0
    09-08 14:49:24.480   9651-10534/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ reset
    09-08 14:49:24.480   9651-10534/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ reset
    09-08 14:49:24.490    9651-9651/com.myaudioservice.app E/PlayerService﹕ stop()
    09-08 14:49:24.620    9651-9651/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ isPlaying: no active player
    09-08 14:49:24.620    9651-9651/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ isPlaying: 0
    09-08 14:49:24.650    9651-9651/com.myaudioservice.app E/PlayerService﹕ start()
    09-08 14:49:24.770   9651-10535/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ isPlaying: no active player
    09-08 14:49:24.770   9651-10535/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ isPlaying: 0
    09-08 14:49:24.770   9651-10535/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ reset
    09-08 14:49:24.770   9651-10535/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ reset
    09-08 14:49:24.780    9651-9651/com.myaudioservice.app E/PlayerService﹕ stop()
    09-08 14:49:24.890    9651-9651/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ isPlaying: no active player
    09-08 14:49:24.890    9651-9651/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ isPlaying: 0
    09-08 14:49:24.910    9651-9651/com.myaudioservice.app E/PlayerService﹕ start()
    09-08 14:49:25.021   9651-10540/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ isPlaying: no active player
    09-08 14:49:25.031   9651-10540/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ isPlaying: 0
    09-08 14:49:25.031   9651-10540/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ reset
    09-08 14:49:25.031   9651-10540/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ reset
    09-08 14:49:25.041    9651-9651/com.myaudioservice.app E/PlayerService﹕ stop()
    09-08 14:49:25.151    9651-9651/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ isPlaying: no active player
    09-08 14:49:25.151    9651-9651/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ isPlaying: 0
    09-08 14:49:25.181    9651-9651/com.myaudioservice.app E/PlayerService﹕ start()
```

**EDIT 2:
-----------------------------------------------------------------------**

I thought I already had it until I got an bug (just at the end of my service) :(

**Edited PlayerService class**

```
package com.myaudioservice.app;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;


public class PlayerService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = PlayerService.class.getName();
    private String URL_STREAM = "rtsp://domain/folder/file.stream";

    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;
    private PlayerCallback callback;
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        PlayerService getService() {
            return PlayerService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            stop();
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Starts playing stream.
     * Note that we just start media player and do not obtain real URL of the stream.
     * So, URL that will be redirected by server will not work. To make such URLs works, adding
     * algorithm to obtain the real URL (f.e., create HttpConnection, connect to the server and
     * get real URL from connection).
     *
     * //@param url String with URL of a server to connect
     */
    public void start() {
        if (mMediaPlayer == null) mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        if (isPlaying()) {
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
            mMediaPlayer.reset();
        }

        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(URL_STREAM);
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            if (callback != null) callback.onPreStart();
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Preparando: " + URL_STREAM);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                mMediaPlayer.reset();
            }
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            //mMediaPlayer = null;
        }

        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "start()");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        switch (what) {
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_IO:
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_MALFORMED:
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_TIMED_OUT:
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED:
                if (mMediaPlayer == null || !mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    // Start MediaPlayer fail.
                    if (callback != null) callback.onStartFailed();
                }
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error");
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START:
                if (callback != null) callback.onStarted();
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Almacenando en búfer");
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END:
                if (callback != null) callback.onPlaying();
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Reproduciendo");
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Reproducción finalizada");
        stop();
    }

    /**
     * Stops playing of the stream.
     */
    public void stop() {
        // stopping MediaPlayer in separate thread because it can take a time
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                    if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mMediaPlayer.stop(); // I get the error here when I destroy the Service quickly
                    mMediaPlayer.reset();
                }
            }
        }).start();
        if (callback != null) callback.onStopped();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "stop()");
    }

    /**
     * Is stream playing?
     *
     * @return true or false
     */
    public Boolean isPlaying() {
        return mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }

    public void setCallback(PlayerCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

}
```

Logcat:

```
09-08 19:15:39.578  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ isPlaying: no active player
09-08 19:15:39.578  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ isPlaying: 0
09-08 19:15:39.578  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ setAudioStreamType: 3
09-08 19:15:39.578  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
09-08 19:15:39.578  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app E/com.myaudioservice.app.PlayerService﹕ Preparando: rtsp://domain/folder/file.stream
09-08 19:15:39.578  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ setVideoSurfaceTexture
09-08 19:15:39.578  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ prepareAsync
09-08 19:15:39.678  27582-31945/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ isPlaying: 0
09-08 19:15:39.678  27582-31945/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ reset
09-08 19:15:39.678  27582-31945/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ reset
09-08 19:15:39.678  27582-27596/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
09-08 19:15:39.688  27582-27596/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ notify(1, 0, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer
09-08 19:15:39.688  27582-27596/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=8, ext1=0, ext2=0
09-08 19:15:39.688  27582-27596/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ notify(8, 0, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer
09-08 19:15:39.688  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app E/com.myaudioservice.app.PlayerService﹕ stop()
09-08 19:15:39.798  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ isPlaying: no active player
09-08 19:15:39.798  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ isPlaying: 0
09-08 19:15:39.808  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ setAudioStreamType: 3
09-08 19:15:39.808  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
09-08 19:15:39.808  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app E/com.myaudioservice.app.PlayerService﹕ Preparando: rtsp://domain/folder/file.stream
09-08 19:15:39.808  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ setVideoSurfaceTexture
09-08 19:15:39.808  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ prepareAsync
09-08 19:15:39.938  27582-31952/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ isPlaying: 0
09-08 19:15:39.938  27582-31952/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ reset
09-08 19:15:39.938  27582-31952/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ reset
09-08 19:15:39.938  27582-27596/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
09-08 19:15:39.938  27582-27596/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ notify(1, 0, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer
09-08 19:15:39.938  27582-27596/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=8, ext1=0, ext2=0
09-08 19:15:39.938  27582-27596/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ notify(8, 0, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer
09-08 19:15:39.948  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app E/com.myaudioservice.app.PlayerService﹕ stop()
09-08 19:15:40.069  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ isPlaying: no active player
09-08 19:15:40.069  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ isPlaying: 0
09-08 19:15:40.079  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ setAudioStreamType: 3
09-08 19:15:40.079  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
09-08 19:15:40.079  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app E/com.myaudioservice.app.PlayerService﹕ Preparando: rtsp://domain/folder/file.stream
09-08 19:15:40.079  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ setVideoSurfaceTexture
09-08 19:15:40.079  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ prepareAsync
09-08 19:15:40.179  27582-31957/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ isPlaying: 0
09-08 19:15:40.179  27582-31957/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ reset
09-08 19:15:40.179  27582-31957/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ reset
09-08 19:15:40.179  27582-27596/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
09-08 19:15:40.189  27582-27596/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ notify(1, 0, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer
09-08 19:15:40.189  27582-27596/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=8, ext1=0, ext2=0
09-08 19:15:40.189  27582-27596/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ notify(8, 0, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer
09-08 19:15:40.189  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app E/com.myaudioservice.app.PlayerService﹕ stop()
09-08 19:15:40.289  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ isPlaying: no active player
09-08 19:15:40.289  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ isPlaying: 0
09-08 19:15:40.299  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ setAudioStreamType: 3
09-08 19:15:40.299  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
09-08 19:15:40.299  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app E/com.myaudioservice.app.PlayerService﹕ Preparando: rtsp://domain/folder/file.stream
09-08 19:15:40.299  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ setVideoSurfaceTexture
09-08 19:15:40.299  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ prepareAsync
09-08 19:15:40.429  27582-31966/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ isPlaying: 0
09-08 19:15:40.429  27582-31966/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ reset
09-08 19:15:40.429  27582-31966/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ reset
09-08 19:15:40.429  27582-27596/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
09-08 19:15:40.429  27582-27596/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ notify(1, 0, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer
09-08 19:15:40.429  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app E/com.myaudioservice.app.PlayerService﹕ stop()
09-08 19:15:40.429  27582-27596/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=8, ext1=0, ext2=0
09-08 19:15:40.429  27582-27596/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ notify(8, 0, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer
09-08 19:15:40.549  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ isPlaying: no active player
09-08 19:15:40.549  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ isPlaying: 0
09-08 19:15:40.559  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ setAudioStreamType: 3
09-08 19:15:40.559  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
09-08 19:15:40.559  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app E/com.myaudioservice.app.PlayerService﹕ Preparando: rtsp://domain/folder/file.stream
09-08 19:15:40.559  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ setVideoSurfaceTexture
09-08 19:15:40.559  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ prepareAsync
09-08 19:15:40.659  27582-31972/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ isPlaying: 0
09-08 19:15:40.659  27582-31972/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ reset
09-08 19:15:40.659  27582-31972/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ reset
09-08 19:15:40.659  27582-27596/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
09-08 19:15:40.659  27582-27596/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ notify(1, 0, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer
09-08 19:15:40.659  27582-27596/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=8, ext1=0, ext2=0
09-08 19:15:40.659  27582-27596/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ notify(8, 0, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer
09-08 19:15:40.669  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app E/com.myaudioservice.app.PlayerService﹕ stop()
09-08 19:16:01.281  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app D/AbsListView﹕ onDetachedFromWindow
09-08 19:16:01.311  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app E/com.myaudioservice.app.PlayerService﹕ stop()
09-08 19:16:01.311  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ release
09-08 19:16:01.311  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ setListener
09-08 19:16:01.311  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ disconnect
09-08 19:16:01.311  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ destructor
09-08 19:16:01.311  27582-32148/com.myaudioservice.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4193eda0)
09-08 19:16:01.311  27582-27582/com.myaudioservice.app V/MediaPlayer﹕ disconnect
09-08 19:16:01.321  27582-32148/com.myaudioservice.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-15992
    Process: com.myaudioservice.app, PID: 27582
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
            at com.myaudioservice.app.PlayerService$1.run(PlayerService.java:129)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Handling videos and images in android might cause Out of Memory Error which arises when your app doesn't have sufficient memory. Share your logcat so we can identify better.

Comment: Thanks @MurtazaKhursheedHussain I know it's not memory problem. Logcat added.

Comment: As you can see there are two errors 1. File Not found and 2. Illegal State.

Comment: No no, the file exist. This info appears when I use setDataSource(context, url) instead of setDataSource(url)) I  just edited the stream url for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

In documentation you can read that [`MediaPlayer.isPlaying()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#isPlaying%28%29) throws IllegalStateException if the internal player engine has not been initialized or has been released.

This code is not thread safe which is probably the reason of this exception (thread call `release()` and before `mediaPlayer` is set to `null` app invoking `isPlaying()` on released `mediaPlayer`). You need to add some synchronization to make it work (or use async methods form `MediaPlayer`).

Comment: How should I do the synchronization?. If in this code, simply replacing the `prepare()` method by `prepareAsync()` does not work and if I try out of `AsyncTask` with `prepareAsync()`, usually, logcat return: `start called in the state 4` if I press for several times the play/stop buttom :(. Now , I tried to remove `release()` from the stop() method and I can interact with my application quickly without it stops. I've added `log` on method play() and stop() and share the new logcat. Audio is played once, and then when pressed for several times... :(

Comment: Adding synchronization to this code may be tricky. I think that the best solution would be to remove `AsyncTask` and use `prepareAsync()` with `mediaPlayer.start()` in `OnPreparedListener`.

Comment: Okay, I'll retry doing what you say. Then let you know how I was. By the way, where exactly I should call `prepareAsync()`?

Comment: Are you really helping me @KamilW and I thank you!. I modified the code to do what you suggested **(EDIT 2)** and the result was almost perfect. I think I'm closer to my goal, but just close my app quickly after pressing the button several times, it fails again with the `isPlaying()` method , this time inside Thread. ):

Comment: Why is this happening if I do not call `release()` method before and mMediaPlayer is not null? Perhaps I should initialize again before `if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mMediaPlayer.stop();`? or should I just remove that line, leaving only `reset()`? It is a good practice?

Comment: Error probably happened because you still have a thread which use `mediaPlayer` without synchronization. To make sure that app wont crash because of that you need to add synchronization to `mediaPlayer` object, but in documentation I didn't find any mention that `stop()` and `reset()` functions take long time to finish  (you using those functions in main thread anyway), so I don't think you need this thread there.

Comment: So in the end, I not need to use `AsyncTask` and `Thread` if I using `prepareAsync()`? I understand? And, if I using in my main activity (where I control the audio with buttons) this code: `@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if(ON_PLAY) moveTaskToBack(true);
        }}` I don't need to call my `stop()` method in the `onDestroy()` of my Service, right?

Comment: When yours app don't freeze when clicking start/stop then you don't need threads. When yours service is destroyed you should release memory by calling `mediaPlayer.release()`.

Comment: Thanks @KamilW, could you look at my answer and take a look at the code and tell me if everything is OK, please?

Answer (score 0):

Ok , I think I finally got what I wanted .
I do not know if I should mark the @KamilW response as the correct because it does have absolutely right but I will answer my question with the right code (or at least think is right) it can be useful to someone else.

**My final code:**

```
package com.myaudioservice.app;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;


public class PlayerService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = PlayerService.class.getName();
    private String URL_STREAM = "rtsp://domain/folder/file.stream";

    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;
    private PlayerCallback callback;
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        PlayerService getService() {
            return PlayerService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }


    @Override
        public void onDestroy(){
            if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                mMediaPlayer.release();
                mMediaPlayer = null;
            }
        }

    /**
     * Starts playing stream.
     * Note that we just start media player and do not obtain real URL of the stream.
     * So, URL that will be redirected by server will not work. To make such URLs works, adding
     * algorithm to obtain the real URL (f.e., create HttpConnection, connect to the server and
     * get real URL from connection).
     *
     * //@param url String with URL of a server to connect
     */
    public void start() {
        if (mMediaPlayer == null) mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        if (isPlaying()) {
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
            mMediaPlayer.reset();
        }

        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(URL_STREAM);
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            if (callback != null) callback.onPreStart();
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Preparando: " + URL_STREAM);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                mMediaPlayer.reset();
            }
            if (callback != null) callback.onStartFailed();
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            //mMediaPlayer = null;
        }

        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "start()");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        switch (what) {
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START:
                if (callback != null) callback.onStarted();
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Almacenando en búfer");
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END:
                if (callback != null) callback.onPlaying();
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Reproduciendo");
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Reproducción finalizada");
        stop();
    }

    /**
     * Stops playing of the stream.
     */
    public void stop() {
        // stopping MediaPlayer in separate thread because it can take a time
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                    if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mMediaPlayer.stop();
                    mMediaPlayer.reset();
                }
            }
        }).start();
        if (callback != null) callback.onStopped();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "stop()");
    }

    /**
     * Is stream playing?
     *
     * @return true or false
     */
    public Boolean isPlaying() {
        return mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }

    public void setCallback(PlayerCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra){

    if(what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN ||
            what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED ||
            extra == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_IO ||
            extra == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_MALFORMED ||
            extra == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED ||
            extra == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_TIMED_OUT ||
            extra == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK){

        stop();
        if (callback != null) callback.onStartFailed();
    }
    return true;// Si hay error, no es necesario llamar a onCompletionListener, por eso: true
}


}
```

I would also like to be inspected by an expert to tell me what I need to improve in the code (if not too much to ask). Thak You.